# Security vunerability - What is this URL trying to do?

Tags: php, asp.net, security

I've just received the following error from a few sites I run:

> Error Caught in Application_Error event
>
> Error in:
>   https:///phppath/php?-d+allow_url_include=on+-d+safe_mode=off+-d+suhosin.simulation=on+-d+disable_functions=""+-d+open_basedir=none+-d+auto_prepend_file=php://input+-n
>
> Error Message:A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected
>   from the client (="Stack Trace: at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
>   collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)

Obviously, the ASP.NET has just rejected this - a good thing.

But what I do not understand, not being a PHP type chap, is what it is trying to do?

Comment: Those are some PHP directives which this attempt is trying to override and manipulate to their benefit. However this will not effect everywhere and only some weakly defended code with some known security loophole will become victim to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attacker has sent PHP code in the HTTP request body, and he is trying to have that code executed by your web server.

The `php://input` references the request body (ie POST data). The `auto_prepend_file` directive allows the script to include PHP code in the same way that `include()` and `require()` work. If successful, the uploaded code would be prepended and executed.

The payload most likely contains a backdoor script and some code to call home to let the developer know that a hack was successful.

This is most likely a bot that has randomly selected your server, as opposed to a human manually attempting it.

The bug that the attacker is trying to exploit is [CVE-2012-1823](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-1823):

> sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c in PHP before 5.3.12 and 5.4.x before 5.4.2, when configured as a CGI script (aka php-cgi), does not properly handle query strings that lack an = (equals sign) character, which allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code by placing command-line options in the query string, related to lack of skipping a certain php_getopt for the 'd' case.

http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2012-1823

Comment: Thanks for the detail - I'm sure it's a bot as it happened on 4 sites all on seperate IP addresses within a few minutes. So, are all patched, up-to-date, web servers able to reject this? And it really is just going to get old, unpatched servers? Or is it just by the merit I'm running IIS with no PHP extensions?

Comment: Yes, patched and updated servers will not be vulnerable to this attack. See my edit for the specific bug that they are trying to exploit.